# How to change the author of the specific commit (Everything up to date)

Tags: git

I am going to change the author of a specific commit but git says "Everything up to date".

What I have done is like below.

```
git rebase -i ed467b32 // ed467b32 is the previous commit id

git commit --amend --author="new auth name <email@address.com>"

git rebase --continue

git push origin branch -f
```

But after that, git says "Everything up to date".

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can we see `git show --format=format:'Author: %an <%ae>%nCommiter: %cn <%ce>' -s` before and after `git commit --amend` ?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you choosing for the interactive rebasing?

You have to edit the commit and then change the author.

Here is an example with one commit:

```
git log -1

commit <COMMIT_SHA>
Author: author_name <author_email>
....

git rebase -i HEAD~1

pick <COMMIT_SHA> ... # This will be opened in your editor of choice.
```

Change `pick` to `edit`, save and leave.
Then you can edit the commit.
In your case you only need to edit the author, so: `git commit --amend --author="...."`
When you are done `git rebase --continue`